# Pro-rata rule and after-tax only Rollover IRA

Tags: united-states, ira, rollover

What-if question....  I have a rollover IRA account that accumulated pre-tax balances from old 401Ks. At the same time I never contributed after-tax money to a traditional IRA.

Would it be beneficial to open and contribute to after-tax IRA to start lowering the future tax rate on withdrawals or conversions from 100% pro-rata to a lower rate?
I'm estimating the 100% rate based on the fact that 100% of the balance is currently pre-tax.

Comment: Are you asking if it would be beneficial to convert your Traditional IRA (fully deductible, i.e.: taxable conversion) to Roth? You can convert pre tax traditional balances as well (in fact, you can't convert *just* the after tax balances).

Comment: Are you above the income limit for direct Roth IRA contributions, and the rollover IRA is preventing you from doing a backdoor Roth?

Comment: I'm above Roth IRA income threshold.
Not planning to do Roth conversion at the moment, but rather contemplating future taxation on withdrawals.

Comment: **The pro-rata rule applies across ALL traditional (non-Roth) IRA acccounts.** IRA is _Arrangement_ (not Account) and you have only one IRA even if it consists of multiple accounts. You can't benefit by creating a new post-tax account and converting only that account. As long as you have significant trad-IRA money _anywhere_ the backdoor Roth is less effective. [ObXKCD](https://xkcd.com/1494/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're able to get those nondeductible contributions converted to Roth in a "reasonable" amount of time (1 year, 5 years, 10 years - kind of your determination on what's reasonable), probably not. And by "able to get converted", I mean without having to deal with the pro-rata rule, so you'd either need to get the pre-tax balance out of your IRA (e.g. into a 401k) or eat the taxes and convert the whole thing.

Why "probably not"? Only your nondeductible contributions would be tax-free, and earnings on that would be considered pre-tax. With an efficient investment strategy, you'd be trading long-term gains in a taxable account for ordinary income in your IRA. Not to mention the lack of flexibility in being able to use your funds pre-59.5. There are a few situations where that could be desirable and beneficial, but it's often not worth the tradeoff.

As an example, you have a 25-year time horizon, will make a $7,000 nondeductible IRA contribution in each of those 20 years, are starting with a $50,000 rollover (pre-tax) balance today, and have an annual average growth rate of 8%.

After 25 years, you'll have $854,165 in your IRA, of which $175,000 ($7,000 x 25) is nontaxable. 20% of your withdrawals would be nontaxable at that time. If your time horizon is longer, your starting balance is larger, or your returns are higher, that nontaxable percentage goes down.

I'd usually argue that it's more advantageous just to have a taxable investment account at that point vs. making nondeductible IRA contributions and not converting. If you're able to roll the existing pre-tax IRA balances into a 401k, which eliminates the pro-rata rule issue and opens the door for Roth conversions of your nondeductible contributions, that could also be a viable option.

There are also other factors not discussed in detail here. RMDs in your rollover/traditional IRA (vs. none in taxable accounts), no step-up in basis for your IRA at your death (vs. step-up for your taxable account), lack of tax flexibility in the withdrawal phase because everything is pro-rata (vs. being able to pick and choose what you withdraw from a taxable account), and more.

Comment: Great answer. I agree that non-deductible traditional IRAs have limited utility except as a vehicle to get your money to Roth. I would also add the record-keeping requirement: if you somehow lose track of your basis, you'll end up getting double-taxed on your contributions.